# Why default template does not show?

Tags: templates

I created a template page called X.php. I used it for one of my pages in the website for testing. Now i want to use the default template (page.php), which will take the data from the database and display it. For some reason even the default template is selected still the x.php template is displayed on the page. WHat could be the reason?

Comment: Is the file literally called `X.php`?

Comment: no, its just an example